# Finding $c$ such that $c\sqrt{n} \geq \log_2 n$ for all $n\geq 2$.

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms, radicals, upper-lower-bounds

I am struggling with the follwing problem:

It is clear to me, that $\sqrt{n}$ is larger than $\log_2 n$ for all $n\geq17$.
This is not the case for all $n\leq16$ though, since $\sqrt{9} = 3 < \log_2 9$ for example.

> How can I find a minimal constant $c\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$, such that $c\sqrt{n} \geq \log_2 n$ for all $n\geq 2$?

I would appreciate, if one of you has a good idea, how to solve this, thank you.

Comment: You can try to simplify $c\geq \log_2(n)\cdot n^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ using logarithm- and powerrules. Then the minimal $c$ is the one that fulfills equality.

Comment: Try $\max \{( \log_2 n)/\sqrt n) : 2 \le n \le 16 \}$. This gives $c \approx 1.061$, for $n=7$. But $c=2$ works fine.

Comment: This is equivalent to finding the maximum value of the function $(\log_2 n)/\sqrt n$, for which there are standard calculus techniques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $$f(n)\equiv\frac{\log_2 n}{\sqrt{n}}\quad\text{for all $n\geq 2$.}$$ Its derivative is $$f'(n)=\frac{2-\ln n}{\sqrt{n^3}\ln 4},$$ where $\ln$ denotes the natural logarithm. Therefore, $f'(n)\gtrless0$ according as $n\lessgtr e^2$, and $f$ reaches its unique maximum at $n=e^2$ on the interval $[2,\infty)$. Consequently, $$f(e^2)=\frac{2}{e\ln 2}$$ is the least $c$ satisfying the desired inequality.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot